# Getting error while subscribing. subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

```js
  var a$= from(['aaaa','bbbb'])
        var b$=from(ajax(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/no8tj`))
        a$.pipe(mergeMap(post => b$).subscribe(res => console.log(res)));
```

I am trying to make use of mergeMap operator. But while subscribing i am getting an error 'TypeError: Object(...)(...).subscribe is not a function'. I am trying out this example from the following link
https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subscribe to `pipe()` instead of `mergeMap` try

```
a$.pipe(mergeMap(post => zip(b$,of(post)))).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Now i am getting the data from b$ but not from a$. Can you tell me how do i get the data from both the observables

Comment: zip to combine them two, res now contains both, updated the answer.